# Hasse principle for quadratic forms over finitely generated fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

Does the Hasse principle hold for quadratic forms over finitely generated fields (e.g. for the Henselisations/completions at height-$1$-primes or all places)?

Comment: What do you mean by the Hasse principle for a finitely generated field?  For a fraction field $K$ of a Dedekind domain, the "Hasse principle holds" for a polynomial system with coefficients in $K$ if there exists a solution in $K$ provided there exists a solution in $K_v$ for the completion of $K$ with respect to every place $v$.  If $K$ is the fraction field of a Noetherian ring of higher dimension, what replaces the "places"?  For instance, are you considering completions with respect to primes of height $>1$?

Comment: @Jason Starr: I have edited my question.

Comment: (Part 1). It is not enough to consider height one primes.  Let $p$ be a prime different from $2$.  Let $q$ be a positive power of $p$.  For an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, every nonzero element of $H^1(E,\mu_2)$ gives rise to a "cyclic algebra" over $E$ when combined with the usual element of $H^1(\mathbb{F}_q,\mu_2)$ coming from the unique degree $2$ extension $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}/\mathbb{F}_q$. This symbol algebra is everywhere unramified.  The associated Severi-Brauer variety is an everywhere unramified conic bundle $C\to E$ . . .

Comment: (Part 2) . . . The height one primes correspond to closed points of $E$.  By Wedderburn's theorem (later extended by Chevalley and Warning), the fiber of $C$ over every closed point of $E$ has a rational point.  By Hensel's Lemma, this rational point extends to a point over the completion of $\mathbb{F}_q(E)$ with respect to the closed point.  Thus $C\to E$ has local points everywhere, yet the conic has no rational point over $\mathbb{F}_q(E)$.

Comment: In the positive direction, it follows by the Tsen-Lang theorem that for every smooth projective curve $B$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, for a quadratic polynomial in $5$ or more variables over $\mathbb{F}_q(B)$, there is always a rational point.  So in this case, the Hasse principle holds (because there are always global points, even without checking for local points in completions).

Comment: @JasonStarr The Brauer-Hasse-Noether theorem holds for global function fields (like your ${\mathbb{F}}_q(E)$) and that should imply such a counterexample does not exist. Could you write down an explicit conic over an explicit $E$?

Comment: @FelipeVoloch.  That is an excellent point!  I guess that my symbol algebras are actually matrix algebras.  Of course there are unramified examples over surfaces.  I will write an answer . . .

Answer (score 4):

The examples that I wrote in the comments are wrong.  Thanks to Felipe Voloch for catching my mistake.  One can, indeed, form the symbol algebras that I indicated.  However, the Brauer-Hasse-Noether(-Albert) theorem from class field theory states that these symbol algebras are actually matrix algebras.  In these terms, the Brauer-Hasse-Noether theorem together with Hasse's Global Structure Theorem (injectivity on the left for the "reciprocity short exact sequence") implies that a Severi-Brauer variety over the function field $\mathbb{F}_q(B)$ of a curve has a point if and only if it has local points in the completions for all places.  So my examples in the comments were *maximally* wrong.  Sorry for the slip!

Nonetheless, there are examples of dimension $2$ or $3$ that are everywhere unramified at height one primes.  For instance, the Artin-Mumford threefolds are smooth, projective $3$-dimensional varieties that admit a conic fibration over a rational surface and such that there exists an everywhere unramified conic bundle over the threefold whose corresponding Brauer class is nonzero.  The nontriviality of the Brauer class is "witnessed" by geometric computations on codimension $2$ subvarieties of the threefold, so testing with prime ideals of height $>1$ should detect this failure of the Hasse principle.

The original construction of the Artin-Mumford examples was in characteristic $0$ (if memory serves).  As usual, the smooth, projective $3$-fold $B$, the everywhere smooth conic bundle $C\to B$, and the "witness" subvarieties of $B$ can all be defined over a finitely generated integral domain $R$ that contains $\mathbb{Z}$.  Thus, there exists an integer $p_0$ such that for all primes $p$ that are greater than $p_0$, for every field $k$ of characteristic $p$, for every ring homomorphism $R\to k$, the base change $B_k$ will be smooth, the conic bundle $C_k\to B_k$ will be everywhere smooth, and the witnessing subvarieties behave well and prove that there is no rational section of $C_k\to B_k$.

Does this conic bundle $C_k\to B_k$ satisfy the Hasse principle?  If the restriction of $C_k$ over every surface in $B_k$ has a rational point, then by Hensel's Lemma, there is a local point in the corresponding completion of $k(B_k)$.  In that case $C_k\to B_k$ violates the Hasse principle (for height one primes).

On the other hand, assume that there exists a surface $B'_k\subset B_k$ over which $C'_k = B'_k\times_{B_k} C_k$ has **no** rational point. Replace $B_k$ by $B'_k$, replace $C_k$ by $C'_k$, and start over (if you like, you can use resolution of singularities of surfaces to make $B'_k$ smooth).  Now the Hasse principle is **definitely violated**, since the Brauer-Hasse-Noether theorem tells us that the restriction of $C_k$ over every curve in $B_k$ has a rational section.

So, one way or another, we get violations of the Hasse principle for conic bundles over a threefold or over a surface over a finite field $k$.